# Singleton bean injected into prototype controller. For the threads accessing the controller will the injected bean be Singleton or prototype

Tags: spring

Singleton bean injected into prototype controller.For the threads accessing the controller, will the injected bean be Singleton or prototype

Comment: Search on google. you will get good explanation

Comment: Singleton, because it's singleton.